# Django create unique function index

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

With postgresql we can create unique function index:

```
create unique index user_date_checkin
on unique_user_date (user_id, (timezone('UTC'::text, create_time)::date));
```

But with Django 3.2:

```
class UserCheckin(GeneralModel):
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   user_id = models.BigIntegerField()
   create_time = models.DateTimeField()
   
   class Meta:
       indexes = [
           models.Index("user_id", TruncDate("create_time"), name="user_date_checkin"),
        ]
```

can only got such sql generation:

```
create index user_date_checkin
    on test (user_id, (timezone('UTC'::text, create_time)::date));
```

And `UniqueConstraint`

```
constraints = [
    models.UniqueConstraint(
        fields=["user_id", TruncDate("create_time")],
        name="user_date"),
]
```

got `refers to the nonexistent field 'TruncDate(F(create_time))` error

So how can I create unique index with function in Django 3.2?

### update

In django source `django/db/backends/base/schema.py` I found:

```
    if condition or include or opclasses:
        sql = self.sql_create_unique_index
    else:
        sql = self.sql_create_unique
```

But I don't have such condition or opclasses in this case

### update

After add condition:

```
    indexes = [
        models.Index("user_id", TruncDate("create_time"),
            condition=Q(user_id__isnull=False), name="user_date_checkin"),
    ]
```

Still don't add `unique` here:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create index user_date_checkin
    on voip_usercheckin (user_id, (timezone('UTC'::text, create_time)::date))
    where (user_id IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does not support functional constraints *yet*. But this feature is already in [development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) and will be part of Django version 4.0 which is expected to be released in December 2021. For now you can execute your sql through a custom migration:

First run `python manage.py makemigrations yourapp --empty` where `yourapp` is the app where you have your model. Next edit the generated migration and add a [`RunSQL` [Django-docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operation:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="create unique index user_date_checkin on unique_user_date (user_id, (timezone('UTC'::text, create_time)::date));",
            reverse_sql="DROP INDEX IF EXISTS user_date_checkin;"
        ),
    ]
```

After this you can apply this migration by running `python manage.py migrate` which will create the index in the database.

---

After Django 4.0 is released you can likely (might change) write the follows:

```py
constraints = [
    models.UniqueConstraint(
        "user_id",
        TruncDate("create_time"),
        name="user_date"),
]
```